# how to display a message for a controlled amount of time like 5 minutes

Tags: javascript

I would like the message below to display for 5 minutes.

"You do not have access to the Time & Attendance system.  If you have any questions, please contact your local Human Resources department."

I have tried increasing the timeout variable to 300000.

```
    var failureMsg = "You do not have access to the Time & Attendance system.  If you have any questions, please contact your local Human Resources department.";
    var customParameter;                // Used for a custom request parameter
    var CompanyName = "";
    var timeout=600;


        if(userInfo.isWebClock())  //If webclock employee, then direct to webclock
          (REDIRECT_WEBCLOCK) ? results.put("action", "WebClock") : results.put("action", "ApplicationMainPage");
        else
          results.put("action", "ApplicationMainPage"); 
        } catch(error){
          cat.error("Unexpected error in SSO script:" + error  );
        } finally {
          if(! authValid){
              cat.error("** Information does not pass validation"  );
              if(defaultEmployee != ""){  
                results.put("result", defaultEmployee);
                request.setAttribute("msg", failureMsg );
                results.put("action", "failureWithMsg");

              }
          }
        }
    }
```

If the failure message is true, the user should see this message for 5 minutes -"You do not have access to the Time & Attendance system.  If you have any questions, please contact your local Human Resources `enter code here` department.";

Comment: How about using setTimeout(function() { // remove the message from the page }, 300000); ?

Comment: Hi, I am pretty new to javascript, not exactly sure how I would incorporate that setTimeout function correctly into the code. Do you mind helping out please?

Comment: Will do later, please be patient.

Comment: Okay... This is a suggestion: `if(failureMsg) { var failureParagraph = document.createElement("P"); failureParagraph.setAttribute("id", "failureP"); failureParagraph.appendChild(failureMsg); document.getElementById("main").appendChild(failureParagraph); setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("main").removeChild(document.getElementById("failureP")); }, 300000); }`

Comment: First checks if failureMsg is not a value considered false, aka null, 0, "", false, undefined... if so, creates a new paragraph with the errorMsg as text body and id failureP. This gets appended to an element with the id main, but could get inserted anywhere basically. Then setTimeout() gets called. It'll wait 300000 ms, so 300 seconds or 5 minutes, then will call the function passed as first parameter, deleting the paragraph. Note: You could also use the timeout variable as parameter two instead of a hardcoded value.

Comment: I tried adding your portion of the code to the end of the script and still no success :(

Comment: My code is just a suggestion. As your code snippet is pretty brief and I'm unsure where exactly you want the failureMsg to appear, it's hard to deliver more precise code. However, looking at your code once again, I guess you'd have to look at the qequest attribute msg at the page you redirect to instead of at the variable failure Msg if I get this correctly. Also, have you tested with a shorter interval as well?

Comment: Here is the beginning part

Comment: var REDIRECT_WEBCLOCK = true
var defaultEmployee = "WORKFORCE";  Only used if there is an error and want to display the failureMsg
var inactiveUserRole = "TERMINATED_EMPLOYEE_GENERAL";
var failureMsg = "You do not have access to the Time & Attendance system.  If you have any questions, please contact your local Human Resources department.";
var customParameter;                // Used for a custom request parameter
var CompanyName = "";
var timeout=600;
var ENC_METHOD = "SSO";
DEBUG = true;  // set to true for extra debugging messages in server_log.txt (Recommend false)

Comment: if (DEBUG) {
  includePolicy("SSO_DEBUG_LIBRARY");
}

var authValid = false;
var processor = new SSOProcessor(ENC_METHOD);


if( processor.validateSSOURL()){
  try{
    processor.parseRequest(timeout, CompanyName, customParameter);
    if( !processor.isValid )
      throw "Error parsing request: " + processor.invalidMessage;

    cat.info("Processing request for user: " + processor.user);  
    var userInfo = new UserInfo()

    if( ! userInfo.getUserSSO(processor.user)) throw "User not found";
    if( ! userInfo.isAbleToLogin())            throw "User not able to login";

Comment: authValid = true;
    results.put("result", processor.user );

Comment: I see. As far as I can tell, you're creating a Single Sign On service; maybe by including a library. After the user signed on, you're redirecting to a page; the results from sign on (be it success or otherwise) get stored in a... dictionary? You'd have to check if the dictionary key msg exists. And if so somewhere add the value of msg (aka failureMsg) somewhere in your html. Then call setTimeout, to make JavaScript remove it after 5 minutes. You'll have to modify my example above to suit your code but the functionality is there as far as I can tell.